# Android, Xamarin: Catch random exception:

Tags: c#, android

I have a bit of an issue - occasionally my app crashes here:

```
    public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(Boolean hasFocus)
    {
        base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if(intInstanz == 1 && boolTutorialWasAlreadyVisible == false)
        { 
            new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this) // if this crashes, we need clean rebuild
                .Title(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Tutorial1))
                .TitleStyle(0, (int)GravityFlags.Bottom | (int)GravityFlags.Center)
                .FocusOn(btnBackground)
                .Build()
                .Show();

            boolTutorialWasAlreadyVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

It works and works and works and then suddenly. This gets solved by cleaning the project. However, this even occurs sometimes on a released version. And this is a big problem. The FancyShowCaseView is an extra component - I have no control over what it does. So is there a way of just catching a crash here and if it happens just "skipping" the .Show(); maybe?

That be very important. Thanks!

Comment: `try catch` is not an option?

Comment: it is a concept i dont understand id rather say.. how would this go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short regarding [try catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) statement is that if a statement in `try` section fails to execute, the code jumps to the `catch` section and executes what is there, maybe showing a dialog with the error or logging the exception. 
Specific exceptions for `FancyShowCaseView` control may be described in component's documentation, but for starters you can use `Exception` class as:

```
try 
{
    new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this) // if this crashes, we need clean rebuild
            .Title(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Tutorial1))
            .TitleStyle(0, (int)GravityFlags.Bottom | (int)GravityFlags.Center)
            .FocusOn(btnBackground)
            .Build()
            .Show();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     //log or show message
}
```

In the end, you may want to make a small research on why the component fails without recovery. `ex` object should give you information about what is wrong.

Comment: o one more thing: does this include literally ALL crashes? such as null objects, empty pointers, etc?

Comment: yes, you can catch all exceptions. But, in the case of common exceptions, you may want to use specific exception like `NullReferenceException` for null objects. Here is a list of them: https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/complete-system-exception/.